TailwindCSS Grid Overflow Issue Below 375px – Grid Divs Exceeding Container Width
I'm currently working on a responsive grid layout using Tailwind CSS, but I've run into an issue that I can't seem to figure out. The problem occurs when the viewport width drops below 375px. At this point, my grid of divs starts to overflow out of the page's container. I'm not sure if I'm overlooking something obvious or if there's an issue with my CSS setup.
enter image description here

<section class="bg-lightestgreen py-40">
        <div class="container mx-auto px-4 grid grid-cols-12 gap-x-8">
            <div class="col-span-12 lg:col-span-5">
                <h3
                    class="inline-block bg-darkgreen text-white px-4 py-2 text-sm font-regular uppercase tracking-wider">
                    year in review
                </h3>
                <h2 class="mt-8 text-4xl font-semibold text-darkgreen">2024's impact at a glance</h2>
                <a href="#"
                    class="inline-block mt-8 border border-darkgreen text-darkgreen px-6 py-3 font-medium hover:bg-darkgreen hover:text-white transition duration-300">
                    Download our impact report
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-span-1 hidden lg:block"></div>

            <div class="col-span-12 lg:col-span-6">
                <div class="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 gap-8">
                    <div class="bg-lightgreen p-6 sm:p-8">
                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between space-x-4">
                            <h3 class="text-5xl sm:text-7xl lg:text-8xl font-indie text-darkgreen flex-shrink-0">3,000
                            </h3>
                            <img src="./images/calculatordoodle.svg" alt="Icon Description"
                                class="h-10 w-10 sm:h-16 sm:w-16 lg:h-20 lg:w-20 flex-shrink-0">
                        </div>
                        <p class="mt-4 text-darkgreen">more clients have access to our carbon calculator tool</p>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Statistic 2 -->
                    <div class="bg-lightgreen p-6 sm:p-8">
                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between space-x-4">
                            <h3 class="text-5xl sm:text-7xl lg:text-8xl font-indie text-darkgreen flex-shrink-0">323
                            </h3>
                            <img src="./images/crowndoodle.svg" alt="Icon Description"
                                class="h-10 w-10 sm:h-16 sm:w-16 lg:h-20 lg:w-20 flex-shrink-0">
                        </div>
                        <p class="mt-4 text-darkgreen">hours of charity work undertaken</p>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Statistic 3 -->
                    <div class="bg-lightgreen p-6 sm:p-8">
                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between space-x-4">
                            <h3 class="text-5xl sm:text-7xl lg:text-8xl font-indie text-darkgreen flex-shrink-0">13.6%
                            </h3>
                            <img src="./images/emojidoodle.svg" alt="Icon Description"
                                class="h-10 w-10 sm:h-16 sm:w-16 lg:h-20 lg:w-20 flex-shrink-0">
                        </div>
                        <p class="mt-4 text-darkgreen">annual staff turnover</p>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Statistic 4 -->
                    <div class="bg-lightgreen p-6 sm:p-8">
                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between space-x-4">
                            <h3 class="text-5xl sm:text-7xl lg:text-8xl font-indie text-darkgreen flex-shrink-0">#1</h3>
                            <img src="./images/trophydoodle.svg" alt="Icon Description"
                                class="h-10 w-10 sm:h-16 sm:w-16 lg:h-20 lg:w-20 flex-shrink-0">
                        </div>
                        <p class="mt-4 text-darkgreen">became the world's largest employee-owned logistics business</p>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Statistic 5 -->
                    <div class="bg-lightgreen p-6 sm:p-8">
                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between space-x-4">
                            <h3 class="text-5xl sm:text-7xl lg:text-8xl font-indie text-darkgreen flex-shrink-0">30+
                            </h3>
                            <img src="./images/heartdoodle.svg" alt="Icon Description"
                                class="h-10 w-10 sm:h-16 sm:w-16 lg:h-20 lg:w-20 flex-shrink-0">
                        </div>
                        <p class="mt-4 text-darkgreen">charities supported</p>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Statistic 6 -->
                    <div class="bg-lightgreen p-6 sm:p-8">
                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between space-x-4">
                            <h3 class="text-5xl sm:text-7xl lg:text-8xl font-indie text-darkgreen flex-shrink-0">2000
                            </h3>
                            <img src="./images/docdoodle.svg" alt="Icon Description"
                                class="h-10 w-10 sm:h-16 sm:w-16 lg:h-20 lg:w-20 flex-shrink-0">
                        </div>
                        <p class="mt-4 text-darkgreen">books donated to schools and hospital trusts</p>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Statistic 7 -->
                    <div class="bg-lightgreen p-6 sm:p-8">
                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between space-x-4">
                            <h3 class="text-5xl sm:text-7xl lg:text-8xl font-indie text-darkgreen flex-shrink-0">600
                            </h3>
                            <img src="./images/user-adddoodle.svg" alt="Icon Description"
                                class="h-10 w-10 sm:h-16 sm:w-16 lg:h-20 lg:w-20 flex-shrink-0">
                        </div>
                        <p class="mt-4 text-darkgreen">new business partners</p>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Statistic 8 -->
                    <div class="bg-lightgreen p-6 sm:p-8">
                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between space-x-4">
                            <h3 class="text-5xl sm:text-7xl lg:text-8xl font-indie text-darkgreen flex-shrink-0">548
                            </h3>
                            <img src="./images/puzzledoodle.svg" alt="Icon Description"
                                class="h-10 w-10 sm:h-16 sm:w-16 lg:h-20 lg:w-20 flex-shrink-0">
                        </div>
                        <p class="mt-4 text-darkgreen">training sessions delivered</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


Problem Diagnosis
At that narrow viewport, the grid system's available space is dominated by the column gaps from gap-x-8. 11 gaps between the 12 columns would be:
11 × 2rem (32px) = 22rem (352px)

Then if we add the horizontal padding to this:
22rem (352px) + 2rem (32px) = 24rem (384px)

Thus, the grid container cannot shrink in width any narrower than this, causing the overflow.
Solution
Since you aren't really using the extra columns until the lg breakpoint, consider using a single column grid layout until the lg breakpont. This allows the column to shrink more:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<section class="bg-lightestgreen py-40">
  <div class="container mx-auto px-4 grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-12 gap-x-8">
    <div class="lg:col-span-5">
      <h3
        class="inline-block bg-darkgreen text-white px-4 py-2 text-sm font-regular uppercase tracking-wider"
      >
        year in review
      </h3>
      <h2 class="mt-8 text-4xl font-semibold text-darkgreen">
        2024's impact at a glance
      </h2>
      <a
        href="#"
        class="inline-block mt-8 border border-darkgreen text-darkgreen px-6 py-3 font-medium hover:bg-darkgreen hover:text-white transition duration-300"
      >
        Download our impact report
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-span-1 hidden lg:block"></div>

    <div class="lg:col-span-6">
      <div class="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 gap-8">
        <div class="bg-lightgreen p-6 sm:p-8">
          <div class="flex items-center justify-between space-x-4">
            <h3
              class="text-5xl sm:text-7xl lg:text-8xl font-indie text-darkgreen flex-shrink-0"
            >
              3,000
            </h3>
            <img
              src="./images/calculatordoodle.svg"
              alt="Icon Description"
              class="h-10 w-10 sm:h-16 sm:w-16 lg:h-20 lg:w-20 flex-shrink-0"
            />
          </div>
          <p class="mt-4 text-darkgreen">
            more clients have access to our carbon calculator tool
          </p>
        </div>

        <!-- Statistic 2 -->
        <div class="bg-lightgreen p-6 sm:p-8">
          <div class="flex items-center justify-between space-x-4">
            <h3
              class="text-5xl sm:text-7xl lg:text-8xl font-indie text-darkgreen flex-shrink-0"
            >
              323
            </h3>
            <img
              src="./images/crowndoodle.svg"
              alt="Icon Description"
              class="h-10 w-10 sm:h-16 sm:w-16 lg:h-20 lg:w-20 flex-shrink-0"
            />
          </div>
          <p class="mt-4 text-darkgreen">hours of charity work undertaken</p>
        </div>

        <!-- Statistic 3 -->
        <div class="bg-lightgreen p-6 sm:p-8">
          <div class="flex items-center justify-between space-x-4">
            <h3
              class="text-5xl sm:text-7xl lg:text-8xl font-indie text-darkgreen flex-shrink-0"
            >
              13.6%
            </h3>
            <img
              src="./images/emojidoodle.svg"
              alt="Icon Description"
              class="h-10 w-10 sm:h-16 sm:w-16 lg:h-20 lg:w-20 flex-shrink-0"
            />
          </div>
          <p class="mt-4 text-darkgreen">annual staff turnover</p>
        </div>

        <!-- Statistic 4 -->
        <div class="bg-lightgreen p-6 sm:p-8">
          <div class="flex items-center justify-between space-x-4">
            <h3
              class="text-5xl sm:text-7xl lg:text-8xl font-indie text-darkgreen flex-shrink-0"
            >
              #1
            </h3>
            <img
              src="./images/trophydoodle.svg"
              alt="Icon Description"
              class="h-10 w-10 sm:h-16 sm:w-16 lg:h-20 lg:w-20 flex-shrink-0"
            />
          </div>
          <p class="mt-4 text-darkgreen">
            became the world's largest employee-owned logistics business
          </p>
        </div>

        <!-- Statistic 5 -->
        <div class="bg-lightgreen p-6 sm:p-8">
          <div class="flex items-center justify-between space-x-4">
            <h3
              class="text-5xl sm:text-7xl lg:text-8xl font-indie text-darkgreen flex-shrink-0"
            >
              30+
            </h3>
            <img
              src="./images/heartdoodle.svg"
              alt="Icon Description"
              class="h-10 w-10 sm:h-16 sm:w-16 lg:h-20 lg:w-20 flex-shrink-0"
            />
          </div>
          <p class="mt-4 text-darkgreen">charities supported</p>
        </div>

        <!-- Statistic 6 -->
        <div class="bg-lightgreen p-6 sm:p-8">
          <div class="flex items-center justify-between space-x-4">
            <h3
              class="text-5xl sm:text-7xl lg:text-8xl font-indie text-darkgreen flex-shrink-0"
            >
              2000
            </h3>
            <img
              src="./images/docdoodle.svg"
              alt="Icon Description"
              class="h-10 w-10 sm:h-16 sm:w-16 lg:h-20 lg:w-20 flex-shrink-0"
            />
          </div>
          <p class="mt-4 text-darkgreen">
            books donated to schools and hospital trusts
          </p>
        </div>

        <!-- Statistic 7 -->
        <div class="bg-lightgreen p-6 sm:p-8">
          <div class="flex items-center justify-between space-x-4">
            <h3
              class="text-5xl sm:text-7xl lg:text-8xl font-indie text-darkgreen flex-shrink-0"
            >
              600
            </h3>
            <img
              src="./images/user-adddoodle.svg"
              alt="Icon Description"
              class="h-10 w-10 sm:h-16 sm:w-16 lg:h-20 lg:w-20 flex-shrink-0"
            />
          </div>
          <p class="mt-4 text-darkgreen">new business partners</p>
        </div>

        <!-- Statistic 8 -->
        <div class="bg-lightgreen p-6 sm:p-8">
          <div class="flex items-center justify-between space-x-4">
            <h3
              class="text-5xl sm:text-7xl lg:text-8xl font-indie text-darkgreen flex-shrink-0"
            >
              548
            </h3>
            <img
              src="./images/puzzledoodle.svg"
              alt="Icon Description"
              class="h-10 w-10 sm:h-16 sm:w-16 lg:h-20 lg:w-20 flex-shrink-0"
            />
          </div>
          <p class="mt-4 text-darkgreen">training sessions delivered</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



